# Python - How to Send a Command to a Web Server

Tags: python

I have been in IT Support for many years but have always been interested in coding so I've started to train with Python.  I'm working on a little coding project where I ask the user for some parameters (static IP to set for the camera, if the cam has a microphone, what they want camera to be named, etc) and then need to push these settings to an IP camera but I don't know how to "send" these commands to the IP of the camera.

For example, here's the command I run from a browser which will set the resolution on camera with IP 192.168.0.9x to 800x450:

***http://192.168.0.9x/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=update&Image.I0.Appearance.Resolution=800x450***

How do I get Python to send these types of commands to a web server (the IP cam is essentially a web server)?

Thanks for any help :-) 
L

Comment: Look into the Python Requests library

Comment: Look into `requests` (recommended) or `urllib2`, as the answers say. If you can write the command as a URL, sending it to the server is the same as trying to GET that url. If you need to send additional content (a POST) request, look for the `data` parameter in the  above libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think urllib2 is solution for your problem :)

```
import urllib2
content = urllib2.urlopen(some_url)
```

Comment: Please use `requests`, forget urlib

Answer (score 6):

Python-requests is an easy to use HTTP client.

To perform your request, start with:

```
import requests

params = { "Image.I0.Appearance.Resolution": "800x450",
           "action": "update"
          }

response = requests.get("http://192.168.0.9x/axis-cgi/param.cgi", params=params)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). This is a third party library, but it's better than the built in [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

```
import requests
r = requests.get(some_url)
```

> Requests was developed with a few PEP 20 idioms in mind.
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> Simple is better than complex.
>
> Complex is better than complicated.
>
> Readability counts.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, I will continue to play in the python playground :-)   (loving this coding thing!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use webbrowser library in python to directly send the command to web page and control the camera. I used this for my FOSCAM FI8918W

for ur query it could be:

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(http://192.168.0.9x/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=update&Image.I0.Appearance.Resolution=800x450)

U can check the cgi commands from FOSCAM cgi reference guide